# drag and drop file upload asp.net or java

Tags: c#, java, asp.net, internet-explorer, upload

i would like the user to be able to drag and drop any file right onto the web form/control/whatever is in the browser and i would want the file to be automatically copied to a specific folder.

is this functionality possible with asp.net?

is there an easier, already existent tool that i can use to do this?

i would also need the feature of the user being able to drag and drop multiple files.

if there is an already existent java solution please let me know!!

please note that i need this to work with IE.

Comment: What does this have to do with Java?

Comment: @Andrew, perhaps one can use a Java applet for this.

Comment: @andrew do you have a java solution?

Comment: @I__  Do you have a Java question?  And note that the first letter of my name is in caps (as is *obvious* from the text as presented here).

Comment: @Andrew if there is an already existent java solution please let me know!!

Comment: An applet could do this (as mentioned by Dilum).  But it would need to be a trusted applet.  I don't know of existing applets that do it (mostly because it is not something I need to do, and have never searched).  You might try searching on 'applet+file+upload'.

Comment: @andr you dont know this even though you've had so much java exp?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nothing much to do with ASP.NET

There is a JQuery plugin you can use for drag-n-drop file upload:
[`JQuery DND File Upload`](http://code.google.com/p/dnd-file-upload/)

Take a look at [`HTML5 Drag and Drop Upload and File API Tutorial`](http://www.thebuzzmedia.com/html5-drag-and-drop-and-file-api-tutorial/) for IE (only works in IE9 though)

EDIT:

After a little bit of googling, I found [`Plupload`](http://www.plupload.com/example_all_runtimes.php) very interesting. It provides `HTML5` Drag and Drop file uploader for supported browsers.

Comment: @frad can i use this with IE? list of compatible browers did not include IE